# PHP Function error handling and returning when foreach loop goes on a variable

Tags: php

****problem/confusion on how to handle this type problem in the php object oriented coding ****

I have customer class which i need to suspend services for customers, however when the customer has pending work types for a service, i need to return a false for the calling function to do the error handle (i cant do it here becos it could be a email,output, or html)

however i am confused how to handle this as if use following code it will return false only on the last condition on the foreach loop i guess, any idea on how to handle this in the coding point of view

```
 /**
   * return false on failier 
   * Customer suspend all services for this customer
   * 
   */
  public function suspendServices(){

    $pending=false; 

    foreach ($this->services() as $service) {

    $pending = $service->hasPendingWorktypes();

    if($pending === true) {
        return false;
    }   
    $service->state()->changeTo(8);  

    }//end of foreach services 

  }//end of function
```

Comment: In its current state, when it finds a service with pending work types, it will quit the function (`return` from the function) and not check any other service that comes after.

Comment: Also in OOP this should not be a responsible of the customer class maybe. Anyway you should better look for code-review and learn about transactions (in programming, not databases).

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions is perfect for this job. The business method calling for the services can then onwards handle the part efficiently for the correct outcome.

```
public function suspendServices(){

    $pending=false; 

    foreach ($this->services() as $service) {

    $pending = $service->hasPendingWorktypes();

    if($pending === true) {
        throw new PendingExcpetion(); //Throw the exception
    }   
    $service->state()->changeTo(8);  

    }//end of foreach services 
}
```

Comment: Returning `FALSE` or throwing an `Exception` only makes a slight difference in the type of error handling but not of program flow, so I suspect this won't make much of a difference.

Comment: @hakre, On the contrary imagine a function returning `false` as an output and not defining the context under whose basis they occured, exception are life savers IMO.

Comment: What I wanted to say is, that the type of error handling is not that important in the context of the question. I probably would prefer Exceptions, too. But I assume that exceptions aren't the answer.